# How to represent a 3 bit counter in Data flow style?

Tags: vhdl, counter

I want to represent a 3 bit counter in Data Flow style in VHDL. But I am getting confused.
Any hints how it is going to be represented.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any example code?

Comment: No.  This question is too vague and broad.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you mean by "Data Flow style". As you can see in [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18682019), it is not a well-defined concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to examine the link provided in Dave Tweed's comment -

> It depends on exactly what you mean by "Data Flow style". As you can
>   see in [this
>   discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682019/confusion-between-behavioural-and-dataflow-model-programs-in-vhdl),
>   it is not a well-defined concept. –  Dave Tweed♦

You might find that none of the three answers (as of this date) are incompatible with each other describing a dataflow expression of a design specification. For a three bit counter such a design specification might look like this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ctr3 is
    port (
        input:      in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        load:       in  std_logic;
        reset:      in  std_logic;
        enable:     in  std_logic;
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        q:          out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of ctr3 is

    signal cntin,cntd,cntq: std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);

    begin

cntinc:         -- 3 bit incrementer
    process(cntq)   
        begin
    cntin(0) <= not cntq(0);
    cntin(1) <= cntq(1) xor cntq(0);
    cntin(2) <= cntq(2) xor (cntq(0) and cntq(1));
  end process;

cntdin:
    cntd <= (others => '0') when reset = '1' else
             cntq           when reset = '0' and enable = '0' else
             input          when reset = '0' and enable = '1' and
                                  load = '1' else
             cntin          when reset = '0' and enable = '1' and
                                  load = '0' else
             (others => 'X');

cntreg:
    process
        begin
        wait until clk'event and clk = '1';
        cntq <= cntd;
    end process;

cntout:
    q <= cntq;

end architecture;
```

> No. This question is too vague and broad. – [Olin
>   Lathrop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/4512/olin-lathrop)
>   7 hours ago

The part of the question that is vague is what features the counter has, and the above example provides synchronous load, synchronous reset and an enable.  Within those bounds it does provide 'hints how it is going to be represented'.

The broad part is in describing what a dataflow description entails.

Brian's referenced and accepted answer:

> "Dataflow" I think is fairly clear here; it DOES describe the flow of data, and it describes it in terms of concurrent statements. But I would add that each concurrent statement is woken by changes on its inputs and delivers its outputs; therefore (the important bit:) there is no correspondence between the order of things happening and the order of elements in the source code. In that respect it has a lot in common with functional programming. And both the first two models are dataflow; in (I) the elements are in logical order while (II) is not.

sensor's referenced answer:

> Dataflow – describes how the data flows.

My referenced answer:

> - Dataflow – describes how the data flows from the inputs to the output    most often using NOT, AND and OR operations.

And the above design specification meets all three definitions.

All three answers are derived educational institution observations on the structure of VHDL design descriptions from particular perspectives that don't lend themselves to generalization without explanation.

I extracted this paraphrase of a larger counter from a design done before the turn of the millennium in an era where an arithmetic expression synthesis license was an additional cost.

This design description analyzes and a simple testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ctr3_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of ctr3_tb is
    signal input:      std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    signal load:       std_logic;
    signal reset:      std_logic;
    signal enable:     std_logic;
    signal clk:        std_logic := '0';
    signal q:          std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
begin
CLOCK:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if NOW > 100 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;  
DUT:  
    entity work.ctr3 
        port map (
            input  =>  input,
            load   => load,
            reset  => reset,
            enable => enable,
            clk    => clk,
            q      => q
        );
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 6 ns;
        input <= "001";
        load <= '0';
        reset <= '1';
        enable <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        enable <= '1';
        wait for 30 ns;
        load <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        load <= '0';
        enable <= '0';
        wait;  
    end process;
end architecture;
```

demonstrates it elaborates and runs with functional results:

[image: ctr3_tb.png]
*(clickable)*